# How do you connect an application to Zoom?

Tags: api, oauth, implementation, code-documentation

I am looking for a way to create an app for an application I already have developed, and use it on Zoom.
So for example: I have a software application on my desktop that uses a GUI to communicate with SQL databases. It can add, update, and delete rows from the database.

What I am trying to accomplish is I want to create a Zoom app that allows me to connect that specific application, and with a single click of that icon, I can open up that software application.

I believe I found the right developing documentation: https://marketplace.zoom.us/develop/create#
but I don't know where to go from here. Should I be making a JWT, OAuth app, SDK, or a webhook-only app?